# loop through json objects and add to dictionary with same key and append to list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop through the json object and add the json values to dictionary and finally append that dictionary to list.
For example:-

```
lists=[]
dicts={}
for objects in json:
   dicts["a"]= objects["abc"]
   dicts["b"] = objects["xyz"]
   lists.append(dicts)
```

Input data json:-

```
{ "json" : [ { 'abc'= 'string1', 'xyz='string2', 'a': 'name'}, { 'abc'= 'john', 'xyz='joe', 'a': 'name'},{ 'abc'= 'b', 'xyz='c', 'a': 'name'} ]}
```

Expectation for the output is list inside the dictionary like this:-

```
[{'a': 'string1','b': 'string2'}, {'a': 'john','b': 'joe'}]
```

How can i achieve this?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: are you getting any error for the code that you tried?

Comment: Not an error but i am getting the same output every time, so my output is :-[{'a': 'string1','b': 'string2'}, {'a': 'string1','b': 'string2}]. So actually the values are updating in dictionary for same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dicts` you are over-writing with the last value in `json` instead

Use:

```
results = []
for objects in json:
    results.append({"a": objects["abc"], "b": objects["xyz"]})
```

Comment: Thank you so much:) Its so easy if i think little much:).Thanks for the help.